# Other than yielding, what type of stress you check for ASD?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses

ASIC 360-16, in page pdf 330, it says
"*For any single element, there may be a number of different allowable stresses that must be checked*."

I can think of yielding. What else?
Rupture for steel too? What else?

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to AISC 360-16, but from experience from other structural codes, I'll hazard a guess.

you can check for allowable stresses with respect to:

- yielding
- ultimate failure
- fatigue
- torsional
- contact pressure
- dynamic loading
- ...

Also, I am not certain, the context of the word '*element*', because that could include buckling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The stresses I believe is referring to the Action on the element, taking flexural or shear stresses as example.

The Load cases and combination of action is important, because of the limitation of the element while facing both flexural and shear stresses.

Example, you can pour orange and milk into a bottle, for the same size of bottle, it may appear that you can pour a bottle of milk **OR** a bottle of orange. However, say if the bottle is already filled with orange, you didn't know, and you thought that it can fill a bottle of milk. It would certainly lead to spilling! That's why you have to check it.